# How to make empty space in a linechart?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, linechart

I'm using the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) librairy in my Android App and I'm drawing a LineChart like below.

Sometimes some entries (values) in my exemple are considered like invalid. I want to represent these values like a empty space that will be drawned between the last 2 valid entries something like;

[image]

Any help !?

Comment: any solution of this?

Comment: Any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done but you need combined chart for that and multiple lines will do the trick. Where you want to break end the 1st dataset there and from where begin again start 2nd dataset.

Follow example below:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CombinedData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IndexAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CombinedChart combinedChart = (CombinedChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    CombinedData data = new CombinedData();
    data.setData(barData());
    data.setData(lineData());
    combinedChart.setData(data);

    // xAxis customization
    XAxis xAxis = combinedChart.getXAxis();

    // Following code have no effect but you can change it if required
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(false);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

    // Setting maximum limit of xAxis
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(barData().getEntryCount());

    // Setting position of xAxis
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTH_SIDED);

    // This is used to fix bar width of first bar
    xAxis.setSpaceMin(barData().getBarWidth() / 2f);
    xAxis.setSpaceMax(barData().getBarWidth() / 2f);

    // Setting labels to xAxis
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(getXAxisValues()));

}

// creating list of x-axis values 
private ArrayList<String> getXAxisValues()
{
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String> ();

    labels.add( "JAN");
    labels.add( "FEB");
    labels.add( "MAR");
    labels.add( "APR");
    labels.add( "MAY");
    labels.add( "JUN");
    return labels; 
}

// this method is used to create data for line graph 
public LineData lineData()
{
    ArrayList<Entry> line = new ArrayList<Entry> ();
    line.add(new Entry(0, 10));
    line.add(new Entry(1, 11));
    line.add(new Entry(2, 12));
    line.add(new Entry(3, 14));
    line.add(new Entry(4, 18));
    line.add(new Entry(5, 31));

    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(line, "Brand 2");
    lineDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
    lineDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    lineDataSet.setCircleRadius(5);

    // set this to false to disable the drawing of highlight indicator (lines)
    lineDataSet.setDrawHighlightIndicators(true);
    lineDataSet.setHighLightColor(Color.RED);
    LineData lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);
    return lineData;
}

// this method is used to create data for Bar graph 
public BarData barData()
{
    ArrayList<BarEntry> group1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    group1.add(new BarEntry(0, 3));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(1, 1));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(2, 4));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(3, 7));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(4, 3));
    group1.add(new BarEntry(5, 8));

    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(group1, "Brand 1");
    barDataSet.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
    //barDataSet.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 155, 0));
    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);

    BarData barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
    //        barData.setBarWidth(0.9f);

    return barData;
}
}
```

Replace barData with your second line data in above example and also bar related things from code then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Someone can try this

```
var colorArray = mutableListOf<Int>()
loop over elements
   obj= currObj[i]
   if(i+1 < size && obj[i] != null && obj[i+1] != null)
      colorArray.add(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.your_color))
   else
      colorArray.add(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, android.R.color.transparent))

val set1 = LineDataSet(values, "Dataset")
set1.setColors(colorArray)
```